# C++ Private Structures

Tags: c++, struct, structure, private-members

I have read that the main differences between classes and structures (other than functions), is that class members default to private, whereas structure members default to public.

That implies that structure members can be private. My question is: Can you have private structure members? And if you can, what is the purpose of using private members? How would you even access them?

Comment: You would access private structure members in the same way you access private class members.  The question only makes sense if you think of structs and classes as different.  Try thinking of them as pretty much identical.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes structures can have private members, you just need to use the access specifier for the same.

```
struct Mystruct
{
    private:
       m_data;

};
```

Only difference between structure and class are:

- access specifier defaults to private for class and public for struct
- inheritance defaults to private for class and public for struct

How can you access them?
Just like you access private members of a class. i.e: they can only be accessed within the structures member functions and not in derived structure etc.

Answer (score 7):

The *only* difference between `struct` and `class` is default access (with the exception of some weird template situations, see Alf's comments below). This means you can access private members in the same way as in a class:

```
struct foo {
  int get_X() { return x; }
  void set_X(int x_) { x = x_; }
private:
  int x;
};
```

Whether you use `struct` or `class`, then, is purely a matter of style. I tend to use `struct` when all members are public (eg, if it's a functor class with no member variables and only public functions).

Comment: well, regarding the keywords there's also a difference in a template parameter list, e.g. `template< template< class Foo > class Bar >`. you can't write that with `struct`. :-)

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach, interesting. I always write templates with `typename` so I never noticed :)

Comment: you can't use `typename` for that (it would be syntax error). Cheers,

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach, Ahh, that's a template taking a type function as a parameter, essentially? Interesting. Never knew that was even possible.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach I believe I am right in saying that one cannot use the keyword `struct` in _any kind of template_, since one must use either `class` or `typename`. The fact that you made the example using a template template parameter is actually a little confusing.

Comment: @Nexus: I think you're talking about template parameter list, and in that case I think you're right. I used a template template parameter just because that is a case where the `class` keyword has to be used.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach Ok, but what is confusing about your example is that `template<template <typename Foo> class Bar> class MyClass;` is perfectly legal. Just wanted to point it out.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that makes this useful is that you can also use the friend key word in structs, so private members can only be used and modified by those specific functions or classes or what not that you want to be able to modify it.  This way the user can't modify those sections themselves. They won't even show up in the auto fill features, at least in visual studio.